# The primitive type of a variable does not have a field x during compilation

Tags: java

I wrote a java program to compare two strings and at the time of compilation I am getting the error: The primitive type int of length1 does not have a field j
    Syntax error on token ",", . expected

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringCompare {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str1, str2;
        int i,j, flag=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first string \n");
        str1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the next string \n");
        str2=sc.nextLine();
        int length1=str1.length();
        int length2=str2.length();
        if(length1!=length2){
            System.out.println("The strings are not equal");
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=1,j=1;i<=length1, j<=length2;i++,j++){
                if(str1.charAt(i)!=str2.charAt(j)){
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==0)
                System.out.println("The strings are equal \n");
            else
                System.out.println("The strings are not equal \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, unless this is for practice, your code is completely unnecessary. You can simply do `if(str1.equals(str2)) System.out.print("The strings are equal"); else System.out.print("The strings are not equal");`.

Comment: @Gendarme Yes. It was just for practice :). I wanted to use very few inbuilt functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a comma-seperated list of conditions in the middle of your `for` loop. You must have an expression that evaluates to `true` or `false` only.

You are free to have a comma-seperated list of initialization statements in the first part of your `for` loop, which is probably what you were thinking.

Read here for more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: He probably means to write `&&` instead of `,`. So that's probably the appropriate fix.

Comment: I substituted , with && but while compiling I am getting the error: String index out of range at java.lang.String.charAt(unknown source)

Comment: @BijoyJoseph That's not a compilation error, that's a runtime exception. That means there's a logical flaw in your code, but it's at least compiling. You need to attach a debugger and walk through the code to see what's wrong, or look closer at the stack trace. I'd suggest reading up on "What is a stacktrace in Java". It will help you immensely. I mean it.

Comment: The error is that you have `<=` instead of `<`. If the words are the same, or only the last letter differs, you will get a runtime exception.

Comment: (@Gendarme And you need to start `i` and `j` at zero, not one).

Answer (score 1):

Because length1 and length2 has the same value in the for loop you only need the `i` variable. Simplify it to be like:

```
for (i = 0; i < length1; i++){
    if(str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: you also have a bug in your code. Lets say your strings length is 3 and your loop goes from 1 to 3, when str1.charAt(3) is called (i==3) it will crash. You need to start from 0 and stop to 2 (i < length1).

Comment: I tried your method but still I am getting a compilation error

Answer (score 0):

The reason for string index of of range error at for for `(i = 0; i < length1; i++)` is that the compiler is trying to access a point in the string which does not exist. It should be `for(i=1;i<=length1-1;i++)`

Comment: your code does not compare the first char which is at index 0 if you start loop from index 1 (i=1).